# One button working Buttons not working in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Sorry guys, But I am new, This is my homepage java class.
IntroButton is Working well, but Feedback is not working, i am
touching feedback button, but it is untouched. mean no output.

*Created by AwaisButt awais.b7solpk@gmail.com on 4/15/2015.*

```
public class HomePage extends Activity { protected void
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
        Button introButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIntro);
        Button feedBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFeedBack);


        introButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this,Introduction.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        feedBackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this,FeedBack.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

XML File

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/homepage">


    <Button
    android:layout_width="139dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"

    android:id="@+id/bIntro"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="FeedBack"
        android:id="@+id/bFeedBack"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Order"
        android:id="@+id/bOrder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="Catalogue"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/bCatalogue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="Web"
        android:id="@+id/bWeb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake:**

You did a mistake, visibility of the feedback button is Invisible! Intro button is getting clicked because it's visible in your layout!

FYI

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
>   layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your OnClickListener() is of type View.OnClickListener().

Comment: Are you sure about it? Then tell me why that OnClickListener is working for the intro button?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set that `button` as `Invisible`.

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="FeedBack"
        android:id="@+id/bFeedBack"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" // here
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

remove that line. It will work.

One more solution is,

you can use this line in `onCreate` method after you find the button id.

```
feedBackButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Good luck!

Comment: What is the redundant answer when I have already mentioned the same stuff in my answer?

Comment: @PareshMayani Mine can be done either through XML edit or in MainActivity through code.

Comment: @ARB Welcome :) Accept if it's helfpful, so it will be useful for future searchers :)